# why is the color of the same element different when displayed on laptop and mobile device

Tags: css

I checked mobile device resolutions according to all device for my select element and i have only one select element on my views, but on the phone it seems like muted.

1. (not worked) I tried this code:

`select { background-color: #2e70be !important;enter code here }`

2. (not worked) http://websafecolors.info/ - i used different color from this website because of safe colors.

I need to set same color for mobile devices.

[from first image laptom mobile resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGtBr.png)

[from mobile phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yeGNY.png)

Comment: on a screen you have a plain color, on the other a gradient, looks like a reset inside your mediaquerie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different browsers style select inputs their own way. In order to remove this styling you can use `-webkit-appearance: none;`

```css
select {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background-color: #2e70be;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option>test </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

well, I had the same Problem, an I was tying all the time to solve the CSS and cache problem, then it turned out that it was a dump browser configuration mistake,
I didn't notice, that I turned on the night-mode on my Brave browser (Chrome base) on the phone, thats lead to all colors had been shifted to be darker (in my case yellow was broun on the phone).

The answer could not neciserly solve problem in your case, but i thought its worth to mention it.